# Better way to get a list of the top level declarations

Tags: haskell

I have a module called `EditorTest` in a similarly-named file.

It imports some modules. It also has some declarations in it, as any Haskell module does.

I'd like to programmatically obtain a list of the top level **available** declarations within the context of that module.

What I have so far is a way to get the top level *local* declarations of this module only, by using `hint`. That's fine, and I figure I could recurse the imports (and so on into those modules, etc), collecting a list of them, then use hint to grab all the available declaration names... but if possible, I'm after an easier way to find the available declarations in a given module. I figure Haskell's API should have some way to do that.

Is there such a thing?

Comment: By the way, I should say that I know that in TH I can obtain an `Info`-like thing, which is similar to `GHCI`'s `:info` command, which is great for finding all the instances of a typeclass, say, but I don't know how I could use that to find all the possible available declarations (including imported ones).

Comment: Do you want that info at compile time or at runtime that you pass it a file and get the imports and functions

Comment: @epsilonhalbe No, I know a way to get the imports and functions, as I described. What I want is to get all the declarations that a module can use within its scope (so that includes all the declarations all the way up the tree of dependencies). I don't care if it's runtime or compiletime, I don't think.

Comment: I would use ghc as a library for this and maybe take a look at ghcid, ghc-mod to see what they are using. Maybe you need cacal (the library) too. What do you think your function getalltld should return​if you import bytestring stuff but it is not installed on your system. How about qualified imports, records...! I think your question is a bit too broad right now.

Comment: I had a bit of an epiphony when I awoke today. To get all definitions in scope is actually as simple as a) getting all the top level definitions of the module under question (which I can do), and b) getting all the exports of the definitions of the imported modules, which I can also do. Nothing else *can* be in scope, obviously! It's still not as good as a semantic solution, but I think it will definitely cover me for now at least. By the way, `hint` **is** GHC as a library, it's some convenience stuff over it, in case you didn't know.

Comment: ... as to if things aren't installed on the system, that will be handled by a subsystem of what I'm implementing. That is, a user will only be able to import what *is* installed on the system, and if one wants something else installed, one will have to run a separate command to do so.

Comment: In [haskell-cafe](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2017-May/126987.html) appears a post related to the topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-answering because it's been a while and I spiked out a proof of concept ages ago, so I'll put it here for others, even if it is fairly messy.

So, assuming we have this file as `TestModule.hs`:

```
module TestModule (g, h) where

import Data.List as L

f = head

g = f [f]

h = L.map
```

Then the following code can be used to show how we can pull out the top level declarations and use them by using `Hint`'s `Language.Haskell.Interpreter` module and the `Language.Haskell.Exts.SrcLoc` module from the `haskell-src-exts` package:

```
import Data.List
import Control.Monad
import qualified Language.Haskell.Interpreter as I
import Language.Haskell.Interpreter (Interpreter, GhcError(..), InterpreterError(..))
import qualified Language.Haskell.Exts as H
import Language.Haskell.Exts.SrcLoc

main :: IO ()
main = do r <- I.runInterpreter interpreterTest
          case r of
            Left err -> putStrLn $ errorString err
            Right () -> return ()

errorString :: InterpreterError -> String
errorString (WontCompile es) = intercalate "\n" (header : map unbox es)
  where
    header = "ERROR: Won't compile:"
    unbox (GhcError e) = e
errorString e = show e

p :: String -> Interpreter ()
p = I.liftIO . putStrLn

emptyLine :: Interpreter ()
emptyLine = p ""

interpreterTest :: Interpreter ()
interpreterTest =
  do
    p "Finding out what the module exports are."
    p "To do this, we grab the text of the src/TestModule.hs"
    moduleContents <- I.liftIO . readFile $ "src/TestModule.hs"
    emptyLine
    p "Next, we find what the import module names are, so we can load them"
    p "To do that, we'll parse the contents of src/TestModule.hs as AST"
    let
      parseResult = H.parseModule moduleContents
      parsedModuleDeclE =
        case parseResult of
          H.ParseOk parsed -> Right parsed
          H.ParseFailed _ errorReason -> Left errorReason
      (moduleDeclarations, moduleImports) =
        case parsedModuleDeclE of
          Left _ ->
            ([], [])
          Right (H.Module _ _ _ _ _ importDecls decls) -> (decls, importDecls)
    p $ show moduleImports
    emptyLine
    p "Now we can pull the module names out of the ImportDecl values:"
    let
      moduleNames =
        do
          H.ModuleName s <- fmap H.importModule moduleImports
          return s
    p $ show moduleNames
    emptyLine
    p "After this we can obtain a list of the module exports for each of these modules and join them together:"
    I.loadModules ["src/TestModule.hs"]
    I.setTopLevelModules ["TestModule"]
    topLevelImportDecls <- fmap concat $ mapM I.getModuleExports moduleNames
    -- p $ show $ do { I.Fun f <- topLevelImportDecls ; return f } -- filter for functions only
    p $ show $ fmap I.name topLevelImportDecls
    emptyLine
    p "Then, we can get the top level declarations of the initial module and add them, too:"
    -- p $ show moduleDeclarations -- AST in haskell types
    let
      localDeclaractions =
        do
          (H.PatBind _ (H.PVar (H.Ident declName)) _ _) <- moduleDeclarations
          return declName
      availableDeclarations =
        localDeclaractions ++ fmap I.name topLevelImportDecls
    p $ show localDeclaractions
    emptyLine
    p "Finally, we have our big list:"
    p $ show availableDeclarations
    emptyLine
    p "Now, what about we get all of their types, just for fun?"
    typesOfAll <- sequence $ fmap (\n -> fmap ((n ++ " :: ") ++) (I.typeOf n)) availableDeclarations
    p $ Data.List.intercalate "\n" typesOfAll
    return ()
```